# SQL finding the max of the difference of two dates

Tags: sql

I have two dates (run date) and (date due). I need to find the largest delinquent date which would be the largest (max) number of days between the run date and the due date.

Logically I would want this to be `max ( datedif ( day, run date, date due))`, however, this code does not seem to run in SQL.

Please help

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Comment: Which date is greatest one?
the Syntax

'code' DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

startdate should be less than or equal enddate.

Comment: Please post your error message, and post ***the actual query you ran***. Don't retype it, copy and paste it. You have multiple typos in your SQL (`datedif`, `run date`, `date due`).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this script

```
SELECT TOP(1) *,DATEDIFF(day,[run date],[date due])) AS DDiff
FROM TableName
ORDER BY DDiff DESC;
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. JaydipJ, I was trying something similar to what you were suggesting, however I was receiving   The main code I was trying to run did not error it just kept running. The main code I was running was ' Select MAX(datediff(Day, a.[run date], a.[next due]) as DaysDelinq
 from Loanlevel_Database.dbo.Loanlevel_Archive a with (nolock)'